# Cannot push objects to array

Tags: php

Currently, I am trying to push multiple objects into an array($columnDefs) via a foreach loop. However, it seems not to be working. Could anyone advice what I did wrong?

```
$startingYear = 2012;
$endingYear = date('Y') + 1;
$yearRange = array();

for ($i = $startingYear;$i <= $endingYear;$i++)
{
    array_push($yearRange, $i);
}


$columnDefs = array(
    array('headerName' => 'Category', 'field' => 'category', 'width' => 180)
);

foreach($yearRange as $year){
   $columnDefs = array_merge(
       $columnDefs, 
       array(
           'headerName' => strval($year), 'field' => $year, 'width' => 120
       )
   );
}
```

Comment: Sure you can https://3v4l.org/5MiK2

Answer (score 1):

For you to add new structures to your array, you will need to:

```
$columnDefs = array_merge(
       $columnDefs, 
       array(
           array('headerName' => strval($year), 'field' => $year, 'width' => 120)
       )
   );
```

In the adaptation I did to your code, above, you can see I an merging your previous `columnDefs` array with a new array structure that mimics your kick start for `columnDefs`.

If you do not tell it is an array it will always override your previous keys (because it does think it is keys and values its adding and not an array)

This will then start outputing:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( [headerName] => Category [field] => category [width] => 180 )   
[1] => Array ( [headerName] => 2012 [field] => 2012 [width] => 120 ) 
[2] => Array ( [headerName] => 2013 [field] => 2013 [width] => 120 ) 
[3] => Array ( [headerName] => 2014 [field] => 2014 [width] => 120 )
...
```

Comment: Your solution is working. However, my production site is running php 5.3.3 version which does not support `[ ] arrays`

Comment: Just replaced `[` for `array()`